# trouble attempting to query latest unique results from mysql

Tags: mysql, max

My table (example)

```
id - console - zone - timestamp - temp 
1  - 1       - 1    - 12:00     - 123
2  - 1       - 1    - 12:01     - 234
3  - 1       - 1    - 12:02     - 236
4  - 2       - 1    - 12:01     - 567
5  - 2       - 1    - 12:02     - 657
6  - 1       - 2    - 12:00     - 864
7  - 1       - 2    - 12:02     - 436
```

My table is updated every 30-45 seconds with new data from various equipment. My goal is to query the table for each console + zone getting the most recent temp entry (which I can do from id as this table is auto incremented)

ideal output would be (example)

```
 id - console - zone - timestamp - temp
 3  - 1       -  1   -  12:02    - 236
 5  - 2       -  1   -  12:02    - 657
 7  - 1       -  2   -  12:02    - 436
```

I have attempted to use `max()` in my query, however it is not performing as desired. I am getting the max of id, but not the temp from that row

```
select max(id), console, zone, timestamp, temp from TABLE group by console, zone order by console, zone;
```

the above query returns the correct number of entries, however as I mentioned the temp will not be correct. I always get the first temp entered in the table for a console & zone. I've looked quite a bit and either don't know what questions to ask or the answer is very simple and is eluding me for the amusement of the gods.

Comment: I fixed the first table, could you do the same for the 2nd one? Have to be off now, but the how should be clear ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called retrieving what's known as a *group-wise maximum* and it's a very common question that gets brought up because intuitively, you would think using `MAX()` in the `SELECT` in conjunction with `GROUP BY` would give you the correct corresponding row, but that is not the case.

Instead, you must wrap the selection of the maximum in a subquery, then do a self join on the condition that the subquery's maximum equals whatever field you're wanting to retrieve the maximum from so that you retrieve the correct row:

Your table structure makes the solution rather simple as your maximum is basically just a unique auto-incrementing ID:

Try this:

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY console, zone
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    tbl b ON a.maxid = b.id
```

Comment: Thank You so much! This worked perfectly. I was off in far left field. Making me think its time to study MySQL more before continuing this project of mine.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it worked! And I would argue that you should *continue* working on your project because the challenges and struggles you face in working on a real project will gain you a more intuitive understanding of SQL better than any other learning method IMO. If you get stuck, just remember we are always willing to help you out here on S.O. =)

Comment: +1 for explanation. Indeed this is counterintuitive. So the results he was getting from his first query were not actual rows but mixed results from different rows?

Comment: @Dil, yes. What happens is that when the rows are grouped with `GROUP BY`, it just simply retrieves the first row that appears in the data, not the one with the maximum value you're selecting on with `MAX()`. So while the `MAX()` value will be correct per group, it will not align with the row selected. You have to be very careful because sometimes it ***will*** align with the correct row, but ***only*** because the row with the maximum value happens to also appear first in the data, and that can be very deceptive in regards to the query working correctly.

Comment: I'm planning on plugging along with the project, just plan on reading a lot more than I had wanted to. I recall having a similar issue once before when I was asked to find all the duplicates in some 3K pages of information. I had used open office base and typed in all the data then spent 2 days getting the query right and printed the results. of course that got double checked too. I still haven't found that file as I recall several inventive solutions were put into it. Again thanks for your help, us hobby guys would be rather lost without it

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.mid, m.console, m.zone, timestamp, temp 
from TABLE t
, (select max(id) mid,console,zone from table group by console,zone ) m
where t.id = m.mid
and t.zone = m.zone
and t.console = m.console
group by m.console, m.zone 
order by 2,3;
```

Comment: I believe the solution is similar to Zane's though it was difficult for me to make sense of at first. Thank You for your help.